# Has_many / belongs_to relation doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Well, there is:

A **player** model:

```
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :team
end
```

and a **team** model:

```
class Team< ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :players

  def to_s
    return name    # use whatever you want to be displayed. 
  end
end
```

Player's **new** view:

```
<h1>New player</h1>
<%= form_for :player, url: players_path do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :lastname %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :lastname %>
  </p>
  <p>
    Klub</br>
    <%= f.collection_select :Team, @teams, :to_s, :to_s %>
  </p> 
  <p>
    <%= f.submit%>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

and methods from **player's controller**:

```
  def new
    @teams = Team.all
  end

  def create
    @player = Player.new(player_params) 
    @player.save
    redirect_to @player
  end

  private
    def player_params
      params.require(:player).permit(:name, :lastname, :team)      
     end
```

Unfortunately, after adding a player (and chosing team for him from drop down menu), i get redirected to player's **show** view and there isn't any info about player's team. Like the info about the team was not added

```
<p>
  <strong>Name:</strong>
  <%= @player.name %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Lastname:</strong>
  <%= @player.lastname %>
</p>

<p> 
  <strong>Team:</strong>
  <%= @player.team %>
</p>
```

Maybe some of you could help me with finding an error here. Thanks.

edit:

my whole player's controller file

```
class PlayerController < ApplicationController    
  def new
    @teams = Team.all
  end

  def create
    @player = Player.new(player_params) 
    @player.save
    redirect_to @player
  end

  def show
    @player = Player.find(params[:id])
  end

  def index
    @player = Player.all
  end  

  private
    def player_params
      params.require(:player).permit(:name, :lastname, :team)      
    end 
end
```

my routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'public/home'
  get 'public_controller/home'
    resources :players
    resources :teams
end
```

Comment: Post your full controller code.

Comment: ive edited my question with controller code

Comment: What?your controller name is `PilkarzsController`?

Comment: nope sry, its just a typo, I'm translating it before pasting it here

Comment: Ok.And it is `PlayerController` or it is `PlayersController`?

Comment: Did you tried my updated answer?

Comment: Did my answer worked for you?

Answer (score 2):

you controller actions are not correct:

```
  def new
    @player = Player.new
    @teams = Team.all
  end

  def create
    @player = Player.new(params[:player])
    @player.save
    redirect_to @player
  end
```

Comment: ok, i changed it, and I've added:  def player_params
      params.require(:player).permit(:name, :lastname, :team)      
    end, but still nothing : /

Comment: is the database correct? you have 2 migration files?

Comment: one migration file for creating player, 2nd one for creating team

Answer (score 0):

change

```
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :Team
end
```

to

```
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :team
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Your controller should look like this

```
def new
    @player = Player.new
    @teams = Team.all
  end

  def create
    @player = Player.new(player_params) #here i guess its a typo
    @player.save
    redirect_to @player
  end

  private

  def player_params
  params.require(:player).permit(:name, :lastname, :team)      
  end
```

Well if its a typo,then try changing your first line of your `form_for` to

```
<%= form_for @player,url: players_path(@player) do |f| %>
```